# ¿Si monto una URI en un Imageview se me cobra como GB transferido en mi plan blaze de Firebase storage?

Tags: android-studio, firebase, url, android-imageview, google-cloud-storage

Estoy haciendo una app de galería que se conecta a Firebase storage para obtener las imágenes mediante getDownloadUrl() que retorna un Uri, esa Uri la monto en imageview.

Mi duda es si el hecho de montar la imagen en imageview cuenta como GB transferido en mi cuota mensual del plan blaze de Firebase, o para que cuente se tiene que descargar la imagen en el almacenamiento del dispositivo.

[image: precio mensual de firebase storage por GB transferido]

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque parece más una duda para el soporte técnico de la empresa en cuestion

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Si, si cuenta como GB transferido/descargado, por que el metodo `getDownloadUrl()` retorna una vez cargada la foto al storage, entonces cada vez que retornes esa URI con `getDownloadUrl()` ya cuenta como una operación hacia el Storage, por lo cual incurre en el almacenamiento y en la transferencia/descarga de dicho archivo.

Por lo tanto cada vez que recurras a la misma URL para hacer una solicitud ya sea con alguna libreria como picasso, glide o simplemente abras esa imagen en un navegador con la URL va a incurrir en GB Transferido/Descargado ya que se requiere una request para abrir esa imagen desde Firebase Storage

Hay dos diferencias entre GB Almacenados y descargados , la primera solo es la capacidad total de archivos que puedes subir al Storage , el segundo es la cantidad de veces que solicitas esa imagen y el costo que tiene Firebase cada vez que carga esa imagen, ese costo se trasmite a GB/día

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sacaste de mi duda